# Dirac Delta on an integration interval with "a" at its endpoint.

Tags: fourier-series, dirac-delta

If we have,

$\int_{0}^{a} f(x)\delta (x-a)dx$

By definition you say,

$\int_{A}^{B} f(x)\delta (x-a)dx=\Bigg\{ \begin{split}f&(a)&,\, if\,A<a<B \\
&0&,\, {\rm otherwise}\end{split}$

But then the interval of integration "must" not have $a$ at its endpoints, but several times I've seen (in my engineering classes) that they just,

$\int_{0}^{a} f(x)\delta (x-a)dx=f(a)$

I would've not noticed if I weren't trying to solve this

$\int_{0}^{a} f(x)\delta''(x-a)dx$

Which the result of the problem (I'm expanding $f(x)=x^4$ in a Fourier series) is just correct if I do

$\int_{0}^{a} f(x)\delta''(x-a)dx=f''(a)$

But that property of the dirac delta is derived by again assuming $a$ does not belong to the endpoints.

So why are these still possible?

$\int_{0}^{a} f(x)\delta (x-a)dx=f(a)$

And

$\int_{0}^{a} f(x)\delta''(x-a)dx=f''(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The expressions are not welldefined. Therefore one often writes $\int_0^{a-}$ or $\int_0^{a+}$ to mark whether $a$ should be included or not.

Since you are talking about Fourier series, I assume that you have an $a$-periodic continuation of $\delta,$ i.e. $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} \delta(x-ka).$ Then $\delta$ is located at the end of the interval $[0,a],$ which is a problem. But you can fix this by translating it a small distance $\epsilon$ and finally let $\epsilon\to0$. However, you will get the same result if you include $\delta$ at one end of the interval, but not both.

Comment: Yes, I have a-periodic continuation of δ. Taking what you said, is this correct?

$\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{\pi+\epsilon} g(x)\delta^m\left(x-\pi\right)dx=\left(-1\right)^m g^m(\pi) 
 \label{eqn: intdeltadirac2}
\end{equation}
$

Btw, thank you!

PS: I plotted the function $f''''(x)$ with its respective $\delta$´s [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xc77kIazc-0CtDOEFfVDfGAzQdDLOu6R/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, that identity is correct.